# Unable to bind keys `M-[` and `M-]`

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to bind `M-[` and `M-]` to the following functions (courtesy of [Xah Lee](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_move_by_paragraph.html)):

```
(defun xah-forward-block (&optional n)
  "Move cursor beginning of next text block.
A text block is separated by blank lines.
This command similar to `forward-paragraph', but this command's behavior is the same regardless of syntax table.
URL `http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_move_by_paragraph.html'
Version 2016-06-15"
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((n (if (null n) 1 n)))
    (re-search-forward "\n[\t\n ]*\n+" nil "NOERROR" n)))

(defun xah-backward-block (&optional n)
  "Move cursor to previous text block.
See: `xah-forward-block'
URL `http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_move_by_paragraph.html'
Version 2016-06-15"
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((n (if (null n) 1 n))
        ($i 1))
    (while (<= $i n)
      (if (re-search-backward "\n[\t\n ]*\n+" nil "NOERROR")
          (progn (skip-chars-backward "\n\t "))
        (progn (goto-char (point-min))
               (setq $i n)))
      (setq $i (1+ $i)))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<M-[>") 'xah-backward-block)
(global-set-key (kbd "<M-]>") 'xah-forward-block)
```

After I add the above code to the init file and save, and then do `M-x eval-buffer` or restart, it doesn't take effect. When I try to move or look them up via `C-h k` it says `M-[` or `M-]` is undefined. But I can see them listed in the describe-bindings buffer via `C-h b`. I also tried to escape the brackets as `\[` and `\]` because I thought maybe they're special characters, but still I've got the same result. But when I change the brackets to arrow keys it works. The version of Emacs I use is 26.2 and OS is Fedora 30. I've checked a lot of places and still haven't found the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Substrings in the `kbd` argument that are delimited by `<` and `>` are labels for non-character input events such as `<mouse-2>`. But, with `[` you mean the character `[` and with `M-` you mean the meta modifier. So `<` and `>` are inappropriate in your use-case.

Use `(kbd "M-[")` instead of `(kbd "<M-[>")`.